# Do complex toru with different parameter have different complex structure

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $\omega \in \Bbb{C}$ with $\text{Im}\ \omega >0$, then using the properly discontinuous free group action $\Gamma$ on $\Bbb{C}$ :$$z \mapsto z+ \omega n +m$$

with $m,n \in \Bbb{Z}$, we get the complex torus $T_{\omega} = \Bbb{C}/\Gamma$.

If $\omega_2 \ne \omega_1$, we know as torus they always has same topological structure and smooth structure. Do they have same complex structure? i.e. exist biholomorphic map between $$T_{\omega_1} \cong T_{\omega_2}$$?

Comment: If the lattice generated by 1 and omega1 coincides with the lattice generated by 1 and omega2, then yes. If not, no. This should be explained in textbooks on complex analysis treating elliptic functions, like Ahlfors's or Conway's.

Comment: Ok thank you Mariano Suárez-Álvarez , I will have a look at the textbook, Oh i remember there something called J-invariant to distinguish the complex structure on the elliptic curve

Comment: The tori are isomorphic if and only if the lattices are similar ( one way is clear). Hence the $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ equivalence. S